# Efficiently extracting a single file from a large tar.xz archive without decompressing the entire archive

Tags: java, compression, gzip, tar, archive

I have a large tar.gz archive, and I need to extract a single file from it without having to decompress and unpack the entire archive. The current process I'm using seems to extract the whole tar.xz file first, and then searches for the specific file I need (e.g., "153381.pb"). This approach is time-consuming and resource-intensive, and I'm looking for a more efficient way to directly locate and extract the target file from the compressed archive.

I would like to know if there are any general strategies or techniques that could help me achieve this goal of extracting a single file from a tar.xz archive more efficiently, without decompressing the entire archive first. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

The current tar.gz archive I'm working with is 106MB and contains around 1.5 million files. I've experimented with dividing the archive into smaller groups of 10,000 files each and compressing them using the .xz format. With this approach, extracting a specific file becomes almost instantaneous. However, I'm trying to determine if this is the most appropriate solution or if there is an alternative compression method that allows for efficient extraction of individual files without needing to decompress the entire archive.

Comment: afaics with Commons Compress, you'd only need to *enumerate* the entries until you find the right one, at which point, you could get a `InputStream` on it

Comment: `org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.tar.TarUnArchiver` seems to be able to extract an entry by path directly

Comment: "Is there a tool, library..." -- Note that questions "seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" are considered off-topic here ([help/on-topic]). Please [edit] your question to comply with that rule.

Comment: A `.tar.gz` file is exactly what the name suggests: a `.tar` file that has been compressed with `gzip` whereas the latter has no notion of “entries”. You can [extract the `gzip` file in a streaming mode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html), to iterate over the entries of the contained `.tar` file until reaching the desired entry but there’s no way around extracting the compressed data up to this point.

Comment: @Holger is right, I was stupidly thinking of a tar.gz as a tar file with *each* entry gzipped ;)

Answer (score 0):

[pixz](https://github.com/vasi/pixz/) should do what you want. It looks like you can reconstruct the archive for your use, in which case you can build it with random access blocks and an index to the tar files using pixz.